# How to fix Intellisense on sqlServer 2008 r2 ....,

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

after installing service pack 1 on visual studio 2010 , i have lost Intellisense in sql server 2008 r2  , what should i do in order to fix this issue ?

Comment: Try http://superuser.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable or check whether these settings are enabled.

- Make sure it is `Enabled Query / IntellSense Enable` (Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+I)

  You can also try to disable it and then enable it
- Then go to `Edit / IntelliSense / Refresh Local Cache` (Ctrl+Shift+R)
- Go to `Tools / Options / Text Editor / Transact SQL / General / IntelliSense / Statement Completation`

  Select **Auto List Members** and **Parameter Information**

If all is already fine or seems fine, you can follow KB2531482 : [FIX: The IntelliSense feature in SSMS 2008 R2 may stop working after you install Visual Studio 2010 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2531482)

> Assume that you install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1) on a computer that has Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM and Cumulative Update 1 through 6 for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 installed. In this situation, the IntelliSense feature in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio (SSMS 2008 R2) may stop working.

And install Cumulative Update:

> To resolve this issue, apply the following cumulative update. This cumulative update fixes the incompatibility between SSMS 2008 R2 and the Transact-SQL Language Service that is included in Visual Studio 2010 SP1.